# Identify boolean function that satisfies some constrains

Tags: functions, logic, boolean-algebra, constraints

## The problem

I want to find a boolean function $f(x,y):\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, where $x=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$ and $y=\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{k}$ are $m$ and $k$ boolean variables, such that:

- $m,k \ge 1$ (so at least one variable in each category)
- $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
          1, & \text{for } \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i, \text{ with } \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i \ne 0\\
          0, & \text{otherwise}
          \end{cases}$

So, $f$ get to be active only when the number of active $x$'s are **equal or more** than the active $y$'s, given that at least one of the $x$'s is active.
This covers also the trivial case of:

$\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i = 0 \rightarrow f(x,y)=0$ (when all variables are zero, result is zero)

I search for a parametric boolean formula, i.e. one that connects the various variables with any logical operators in some order, no matter the $m,k$.

Note that if the formula's condition is a strict equality $(\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i \gt \sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i)$, and this is an easier problem, it's still acceptable.
And it makes more sense to me to include all variables in the formula of $f$.

## What I've tried

No spotaneous idea came to my mind and so I thought to start with small examples and by computing the **DNF forms** from the truth tables, maybe I will start seeing some patterns.
I have some cases written here:

1. $m=k=1$

```
x1 | y1 | f
-----------  
0  | 0  | 0  
0  | 1  | 0
1  | 0  | 1
1  | 1  | 1
```

$f=x1$. No $y1$ at all here!

2. $m=1,k=2$

```
x1 | y1 | y2 | f  
----------------  
0  | 0  | 0  | 0  
0  | 0  | 1  | 0  
0  | 1  | 0  | 0  
0  | 1  | 1  | 0  
1  | 0  | 0  | 1  
1  | 0  | 1  | 1  
1  | 1  | 0  | 1  
1  | 1  | 1  | 0
```

$f=(x1$ AND NOT $y1)$ OR $(x1$ AND NOT $y2)$. Nice. Seems like a pattern.

3. $m=2,k=1$

```
x1 | x2 | y1 | f  
----------------  
0  | 0  | 0  | 0  
0  | 0  | 1  | 0  
0  | 1  | 0  | 1  
0  | 1  | 1  | 1  
1  | 0  | 0  | 1  
1  | 0  | 1  | 1  
1  | 1  | 0  | 1  
1  | 1  | 1  | 1
```

$f=(x1$ OR $x2)$. No $y1$ again.

---

Maybe it can be proven that no such boolean function exists?
If that is the case, I believe there should be an approximation function, i.e. a boolean function whose results are as close as possible to the ideal one that I am asking for? How to find the best possible one in this case? Could it be the one I saw in the examples above, i.e. $f=\bigwedge\limits_{i,j=1}^{m,k} (x_i$ AND NOT $y_j)$? How would someone prove that?

Comment: Your second condition contradicts your third one, i.e. they are incompatible (f must be 0 and 1 at the same time)

Comment: Also, what must $f(x,y)$ be equal to if neither of the conditions is satisfied (for example, if all the $x_i$ are zero and all the $y_j$ are $1$) ? If you really want equivalence, $f$ cannot be $0$ or $1$ in this case. Perhaps you want just implication, not equivalence

Comment: @NeitherNor I updated the function declaration, does that make it more clear?

Comment: The last row of your first example should have $f=1$.

Comment: @RobPratt True, I corrected it as such. I did some tests with truth tables with the non-strict inequality and that's where that came from.

Comment: I don't understand your issue here. You defined the function completely in the build up. What is wrong with that definition? Is there some life or death reason it must be stated in terms of ands, ors, and nots?

Comment: @PaulSinclair xaxa, I wouldn't call it life or death situation but it is very interesting for me to know if there is such a function or what is the best approximation for it. The case where I am using such functions is in the biology domain where the $x,y$ vectors represent activators and inhibitors of target molecules and a more constructed boolean definition of a target (as in the DNF form for example) that satisfies those constraints I am using, the more deep I get to a mechanistic explanation of the end result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boolean function is simply a function on boolean variables that produces a boolean result. There is no requirement that it must built in a certain way.

However, if you insist that you want some chain of logical operators, for any fixed $m,k$ we can build such an $f$. Suppose for now that $m \ge k$.

Note that $x$ has at least as many active values as $y$, if and only if there is a way to match up the elements of $x$ with $y$ so that every active element of $y$ is matched with an active element of $x$. That is, if $x_i$ and $y_j$ are matched, then either $y_j = 0$ or $x_i = 1$, or in symbols, $y_j \implies x_i$.

To formalize this, define a *pairing* to be a set $P \subset \{1, \ldots, m\} \times \{1, \ldots k\}$ such if $(i, j), (r,s) \in P$, then $i = r \iff j = s$, and for all $1 \le j \le k$, there exists some $i$ such that $(i,j) \in P$. Let $\scr P$ be the set of all such pairings. If $p \in P \in \mathscr P$, denote its coordinates by $p = (i_p, j_p)$.

So $x$ has at least as many active elements as $y$ if and only if there exists a $P\in \scr P$ such that
$$\bigwedge_{p\in P} (y_{j_p} \implies x_{i_p})$$
That is, when
$$\bigvee_{P \in \mathscr P}\bigwedge_{p\in P} (y_{j_p} \implies x_{i_p})$$

is true. So $$f(x,y) = \bigvee_{P \in \mathscr P}\bigwedge_{p\in P} (y_{j_p} \implies x_{i_p})$$

When $m < k$, there are no pairings. Instead define a *partial pairing* as a tuple $(P, Q)$ where $P$ is a pairing of some $m$ elements of $\{1,\ldots, k\}$ with $\{0,\ldots, m\}$, and $Q$ is the set of $k-m$ indices that were not paired. Let $\scr Q$ be the set of partial pairings.

Now we can express
$$f(x,y) = \bigvee_{(P,Q) \in \mathscr Q}\left(\bigwedge_{p\in P} (y_{j_p} \implies x_{i_p})\wedge \bigwedge_{j \in Q} (\lnot y_j)\right)$$

`<Edit>`
The above only encodes $x$ having as many active values as $y$. To also encode that at least one value must be active, we have

$$f(x,y) = \left(\bigvee_{i=1}^m x_i\right) \wedge \left(\bigvee_{(P,Q) \in \mathscr Q}\left(\bigwedge_{p\in P} (y_{j_p} \implies x_{i_p})\wedge \bigwedge_{j \in Q} (\lnot y_j)\right)\right)$$
`</Edit>`

All this bit about pairings is just a way of expressing the short-hand notation that holds for every $m,k$. For a particular $m,n$, it is just a matter of listing every every possible pairing. For example, when $m = k = 2$, this is

$$f(x, y) = \left(x_1 \vee x_2\right) \wedge \left(\left[ (y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_2) \right] \vee  \left[(y_1 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_1) \right]\right)$$

but as $m, k$ get larger, this quickly grows into a ridiculously long expression. But despite that, it still accurately represents $f(x,y)$.

There are undoubtedly simpler expressions that are equivalent. But what this shows is that it is always possible to express $f(x,y)$ in terms of logical operators. Which is something that is true of any boolean function.

`<Edit>` Adding a few simple examples.

To simplify the functions, I'm just doing "$x$ has at least as many active elements as $y$". To get the actual condition of the question, "and" the functions with $(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee \ldots \vee x_m)$.

If we match a set $a$ of three variables with set $b$ of two, there are $6$ possible pairings between them, each with one member of $a$ left over:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
\hline
p_1 & b_1 & b_2 & - \\
p_2 & b_2 & b_1 & - \\
p_3 & b_1 & - & b_2 \\
p_4 & b_2 & - & b_1 \\
p_5 & - & b_1 & b_2 \\
p_6 & - & b_2 & b_1
\end{array}$$

If $a = x$ and $b = y$, then each pairing is represented by the expressions
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
p_1 & (y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_2) \\
p_2 & (y_2 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_1 \implies x_2) \\
p_3 & (y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_3) \\
p_4 & (y_2 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_1 \implies x_3) \\
p_5 & (y_1 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_3) \\
p_6 & (y_2 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_1 \implies x_3)
\end{array}$$
When $x$ has the extra elements, it doesn't matter if they are active or not, so nothing has to be added for them.
When $x$ has more or equal active elements, at least one of these statements will be true, and vice versa. So the total condition is

$$\begin{align}f(x,y) =\ &[(y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_2)]\ \vee \\
&[(y_2 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_1 \implies x_2)]\ \vee \\
&[(y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_3)]\ \vee \\
&[(y_2 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_1 \implies x_3)]\ \vee \\
&[(y_1 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_3)]\ \vee \\
&[(y_2 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_1 \implies x_3)]\end{align}$$

If $a = y, b = x$, so it is $y$ that has the unmatched elements, then it is necessary to guarantee that the unmatched elements are not active:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
p_1 & (y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_2) \wedge \lnot y_3 \\
p_2 & (y_1 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_1) \wedge \lnot y_3 \\
p_3 & (y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge \lnot y_2 \wedge (y_3 \implies x_2) \\
p_4 & (y_1 \implies x_2) \wedge \lnot y_2 \wedge (y_3 \implies x_1) \\
p_5 & \lnot y_1 \wedge (y_2 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_3 \implies x_2) \\
p_6 & \lnot y_1 \wedge (y_2 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_3 \implies x_1)
\end{array}$$

And again, we "or" the various pairings together to get the full function:
$$\begin{align}f(x,y) =\ &[(y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_2) \wedge \lnot y_3]\ \vee \\
&[(y_1 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_1) \wedge \lnot y_3]\ \vee \\
&[(y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge \lnot y_2 \wedge (y_3 \implies x_2)]\ \vee \\
&[(y_1 \implies x_2) \wedge \lnot y_2 \wedge (y_3 \implies x_1)]\ \vee \\
&[\lnot y_1 \wedge (y_2 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_3 \implies x_2)]\ \vee \\
&[\lnot y_1 \wedge (y_2 \implies x_2) \wedge (y_3 \implies x_1)]\end{align}$$
`<\Edit>`

Comment: Hi Paul and thanks for the answer! Some questions: I don't understand what do you mean by $y_1 \Rightarrow x_1$ - is this the same as the IMPLY gate (that is NOT $x_1$ OR $y_1$)? The example that you give in the end is for $m=k=2$ or $m=n=2$? I want to write the expression of $f$ for the examples I have given to see if it matches the truth table results (I have implemented also a program to test it's verification up to $n=20$ or so)

Comment: Yes $\implies$ is a very common notation for implies, and is $\lnot y_1 \vee x_1$ (you wrote it backwards). And I meant $k$, not $n$. It is now corrected. As I noted, this particular expression grows very fast in size, so you will find entering any version for $n =20$ to be beyond reason. For $m = k = 10$, there are $10 \times 10!$ - about 36 million - implications in the expression.

Comment: Ok! But how the latest equation you wrote does not have any $y_2$? Also, for the simple case $m=k=1$, $f=x_1 \lor \lnot y_1$, right? But isn't that different from the one I found? Maybe you didn't consider the constraint $\sum x_i \ne 0$ for the activation of $f(x,y)$ in your proposed solution?

Comment: The missing $y_2$ was just a typo, now corrected. And yes, my version is simply for "$x$ having at least as many active values as $y$". I didn't think to include an exception for the case of everything inactive. That isn't hard to add - just "and" the current expression with $$(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee \ldots \vee x_m)$$

Comment: Hi Paul. I will check it this week and let you know. I believe there is a more subtle DNF form for these expressions. Give me some time and I will get back at you!

Comment: I guarantee that there are much, much nicer forms. All this shows is that some form exists. It makes no attempt at all at being the simplest.

Comment: It has gotten really complicated for me to see which is which in each case. The logic behind it still eludes me :) but at least I can work with simple examples to optimize the function to a smaller DNF form. Can you please create a *cases* function to show the end result (If I understood correctly the result is different for $m\ge k$ and $m\lt k$)?

Comment: Hi! Do you have time to update the answer? I just want to completely understand your proposed function and with some examples find a more subtle DNF form. The answer is excellent, I am just waiting for that last input to accept it!

Comment: The basic idea is pretty simple. Most of the complication is just trying to establish a notation for it. I guess the idea itself was hidden by that. If $x$ has at least as many $1$s as $y$, then the $1$s of $y$ can all be matched one-to-one with a $1$ of $x$. So for some matching $y_i \leftrightarrow x_{j_i}, y_i \implies x_{j_i}$ is always true and any unmatched $y_i$ are all $0$. So for some matching, the "and" of all such statements is true. So if you "or" together those statements for every possible matching, The result will be true when $x$ has as many $1$s as $y$.

Comment: I've added examples for the cases $m =3, k =2$ and $m = 2, k = 3$, though I left off "and"ing the first with $x_1 \vee x_2 \vee x_3$, and the second with $x_1 \vee x_2$ to exclude the "everything is inactive" case.

Comment: Many thanks! Another last thought on this: what would be the  logic of making the $p_i$ statements for the matchings when the rule now was the $x$ has strictly more active elements than $y$? Would be to have the same match as before (every active $y$ matches an active $x$ + there is one more $x_i$ as active always like this: $(y_1 \implies x_1) \wedge (y_2 \implies x_2) \wedge x_3$ - or there is some simpler way to think about it?

Comment: One simple (but again, highly inefficient) way would be to take the functions $f(x,y)$ for $x$ has at least as many actives as $y$), and combine them as $$f(x,y) \wedge \lnot f(y, x)$$ I.e., $x$ has at least as many actives as $y$, but $y$ does not have as many actives as $x$.

Comment: Nice idea, very constructive! Why though the function $g(x,y)=\lnot f(y,x)$ is not enough in this case?

Comment: Also (I know, I know, but my curiosity is killing me!), what is the formula for enumerating all the possible pairings? I was thinking that this is similar to a matching problem in a bipartite graph that has $m$ vertices on one side and $k$ vertices on the other - so all such possible matchings should be $\binom{m}{2} \times \binom{k}{2} \sim \mathcal{O}(m! \times n!)$, right? But you wrote for $m=k=10$: $10 \times 10!$ so did I got it wrong or you forgot a permutation sign?

Comment: The bipartite graph vertices don't have to be paired up one-to-one. Assuming that $k \le m$, there are $m \choose k$ ways of choosing the $k$ variables from the $m$ side to be matched, and $k!$ ways to match them 1-1 with the $k$ side variables, for a total of $${m \choose k}k! = \frac {m!}{(m-k)!}$$ possible pairings. When $m = k$, this is just $m!$. The extra factor of $10$ is because I was counting implications, and each pairing leads to $10$ implications. When $k > m$, just reverse their roles.

Comment: You are correct $\lnot f(y,x)$ is sufficient. I answered on my lunch break, and just tossed out my first idea for lack of time.