# Solver for finding fixpoints of a boolean system

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, boolean-algebra

## Intro: The Problem

My problem relates to solving a **system of equations** that find the *fixpoint* of a studied boolean system ($F(X)=X$).

## A Simple Example

Let $\bar{x}=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\} \in \{0,1\}$ be some boolean variables of interest.
Let $F=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ be the *update functions* for these variables (i.e. $x_i(t+1) = f_i(x(t))$), defined as the follow condition functions (they are based on the inputs of each variable - node in the corresponding graph conceptualization):

$f_1 = \begin{cases} 
    1, -x_2 \ge 0 \\ 
    0, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$,
$f_2 = \begin{cases} 
    1, x_1-x_3 \ge 0 \\ 
    0, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$,
$f_3 = \begin{cases} 
    1, x_1+x_3 \ge 0 \\ 
    0, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

These functions are inspired by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767774/identify-boolean-function-that-satisfies-some-constrains/).

The goal is to to find **answer sets** $\bar{x}$ (could be zero, one or many per se) for which $F(\bar{x})=\bar{x}$.

The above example is of course a very simple case.
In the end I would like to solve such system of equations with hundreds of variables.
Note that the condition functions **will always be linear combinations of each variable's inputs and the variables always boolean**.

## The Question

I need an *efficient* solver for this kind of problem (which is known to be *NP-hard* btw!). E.g. can this problem formulated as constraint programming and solved using Answer Set Programming (ASP) techniques?

Comment: Since you do recognize that your problem is hard, how "efficient" to you want your solver to be?

Comment: @DUO, well, fastest wins right? :) I was already interested in using ASP techniques and I got several proposed answers (via potassco mailing list) that encode and solve this problem and I am going to benchmark these against larger instances to see how far can ASP get me. If there is a proposal for a different solver that I could use, well I might try that as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that ASP can be used to solve this problem! Here I provide a possible encoding of the problem in a file named `fp.lp`:

```
% variables                                                                     
var(1..3).                                                                      
                                                                                
% functions                                                                     
% f(Function,Coefficient,Variable)                                              
f(1,-1,2).                                                                      
                                                                                
f(2,1,1).                                                                      
f(2,-1,3).                                                                      
                                                                                
f(3,1,1).                                                                       
f(3,1,3).                                                                       
                                                                                
% guess assignment to variables                                                 
{ init(V) : var(V) }.                                                           
                                                                                
% compute functions                                                             
next(F) :- var(F), #sum { C,V : f(F,C,V), init(V) } >= 0.                       
                                                                                
% check if fixed point                                                          
:- init(V), not next(V).                                                        
:- next(V), not init(V).                                                        
                                                                                
#show next/1.                                                                   
#show init/1.
```

Using `clingo` (version `5.4.0`) from the command line: `clingo fp.lp` we get **UNSATISFIABLE** for this particular instance.

Commenting the fact `%f(2,1,1).` and running again the `clingo` solver we get:

```
Answer: 1
next(3) init(1) init(3) next(1)
SATISFIABLE
```

Variables that are returned both in the `init/1` and `next/1` predicates are translated to active boolean variables (1) and those that are missing to inactive values (0).
The returned result is thus the boolean vector $\bar{x}=\{x_1=1,x_2=0,x_3=1\}$.

Credits for this answer go to Roland Kaminski.
Various other members of the ASP potassco community provided helpful comments and solutions.
For more info on ASP, check: https://potassco.org/